# Copying model instances from one model to another

Tags: django

I'm using django and struggling with model to model inheritance. I have two models model A and B.
I want to press a button in the html, which will copy a unique onbect instance from model A and create that same instance in model B, I then delete want to delete the single object instance in model A.

Model A is Customer quotes and Model B is Customermarketplacequote, please see views.py below.
The below code is not actioning the request? is there a smarter way to do this, or a way to modify the code, below.

Appreciate any help or guidance.

Views.py

```
def cust_create_marketplace_quote(request, id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        quote = Customerquote.objects.get(pk=pk)
        context = {
        'quote': quote,
        'values': quote,
        }
        quote = Customermarketplacequote(request.POST)
        if quote.is_valid():
            quote.save()
            return redirect('manage-quotes')
    else:
        return render(request,'sub/customer_marketplace_quotes.html')
```

Best,

Serick

Answer (score 0):

I must say I am a newbie, but where do you define pk variable for the `quote = Customerquote.objects.get(pk=pk)` ?
Also I suppose request.POST contains pk/id and then `Customermarketplacequote(request.POST)` is looking for that particular object ...? (I might be wrong here, not sure)

Comment: should be quote = Customerquote.objects.get(pk=id)